# If $a_{n+1}=\frac{3+a_n^2}{a_n+1}$ and $a_1=1$, then what is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^n(3-a_n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, self-learning

**Question:**

> If $a_{n+1}=\frac{3+a_n^2}{a_n+1}$ and $a_1=1$, then what is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^n(3-a_n)$ ?

**My approach:**

I am able to prove separately that the sequence $a_n$ is convergent and $\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^n$ is divergent.

But I somehow cannot find out how will their multiplication behave..
[image]
[image]
[image]

But as I cant conclude about the convergence of the entire sequence within the required limit, I cannot find the limit.

Please help

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot write $$  \lim_n (4/3)^n (3-a_n) = \lim_n (4/3)^n \lim_n (3-a_n),$$ because at least one term at the RHS does not exist.

Comment: Simple example: $(a_n = n)_1^\infty$ diverges, $(b_n = 1/n)_1^\infty$ converges, but $a_n b_n = 1$ could converge.

Comment: Yes, I get you...Even I doubted this method..Then how can I solve this sum ? Can you help me?

Comment: The sequence $\left(\frac43\right)^n(3-a_n)$ converges to a finite positive limit. What makes you think one can identify the value of this limit?

Comment: @Did Not that I have a strong knowledge of real analysis..It is convergent means it must have an upper bound..Is it not always possible to obtain the value of the upper bound?Does that mean that the value of the limit can't be found out?

Comment: Finding an upper bound of $b_n=\left(\frac43\right)^n(3-a_n)$ is a piece of cake since $(b_n)$ is decreasing and $b_1$ is known. Identifying the limit of $(b_n)$ is quite another story. But, reading your comments, I am not sure you see the difference between these two tasks.

Comment: @Did I realised that tge sequence has no upper bound as it is decreasing..I wanted to mean the sequence is bounded but unfortunately coudnot edit the comment..Really sorry for that..The Monotone convergence theorem states that "If a sequence is decreasing and is bounded below by an infimum, it will converge to the infimum."..lim(n->inf) of the given sequence should be that infimum..I tried to say that...Am I correct or my thinking direction is wrong?

Comment: "t[h]e sequence has no upper bound as it is decreasing" ?? Every decreasing sequence has a finite upper bound.

Comment: "Am I correct or my thinking direction is wrong?" Again, establishing the convergence is easy but identifying the limit is not. // Say, where did you find this question? I am asking because the gap between the level of the question and the level of your knowledge seems huge...

Comment: Yes it does..In this case  the 1st value of the sequence..But as it is decreasing that should not be of any help here to find the limit..I have mentioned earlier that I am just a beginner in this Real Analysis part..So it would be very kind of you, if you tell me how should I think about this sum and what are the important topics I should study for making my concept clear and understanding this sum..

Comment: @Did A friend asked me to solve..We are just beginners in this topic.

Comment: Then ask your friend to confirm that they asked you to identify the limit, not simply to show the convergence. Because now, you are just abusing the site...

Comment: With due respect, I really dont get it Sir, that how does asking a question, mentioning clearly my view point and knowledge about this question gets me to abuse this site..I respect this place, have been here for about a year and I know that people here including you have good knowledge of topics where as I am just a beginner..I self study with some friends and not always that I have someone to show me how to solve a particular sum..Thus I come here to know ..I appologize any rude behaviour from me..

Comment: Sorry but if you think the mess spread all over this page is how the site is supposed to function then your conception of the site is deeply flawed. (Using @ to address what some other user said, would be a first step to using said site correctly.)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I misunderstood the question. This answer only proves convergence, but doesn't find the limit.

Let's try looking at rations again:

$$
\begin{align}
R_n = \frac{(\frac{4}{3})^{n+1}(3-a_{n+1})}{(\frac{4}{3})^{n}(3-a_{n})} &=
\frac{4}{3} \times \frac{3-\frac{3+a_n^2}{a_n+1}}{3-a_{n}} =
\frac{4}{3} \times \frac{\frac{3a_n + 3 - 3 - a_n^2}{a_n+1}}{3-a_{n}} = \\
&= \frac{4}{3} \times \frac{a_n(3-a_n)}{(a_n+1)(3-a_{n})} =
\frac{4}{3} \times \frac{a_n}{a_n+1}
\end{align}
$$

We know that $a_n < 3$. Since $\frac{x}{x+1}$ is increasing, $\frac{a_n}{a_n+1} < \frac{3}{4}$. Therefore, $R_n < 1$.

Note that we're not doing ratio test (ratio test is for series, not for sequences), and we don't need to take the limit of $R_n$.

Instead, knowing that $R_1<1$, we can conclude that the sequence is decreasing. It's also positive, so it must converge.

Comment: Thank you..But now that we know, the sequence is convergent, how can I find the given limit, i.e, lim[(4/3)^n](3-a_n) ?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I don't know how to get that. You should probably unaccept this answer though, as when it's accepted people will this the question resolved.

Comment: Thank you for your answer anyway :)

Comment: I obtained the limit as a convergent infinite series, but they again involve $a_n$'s, so could not the explicit value of it.